# Как удалить старые сцены из билда Unity?

Tags: разработка-игр, unity3d

Как удалить старые сцены из билда Unity?

[image: билд]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выделите сцену которую хотите удалить, и нажмите кнопку(на клавиатуре!)`delete`.

Comment: Будьте добры, подсказать,где находится кнопка удалить(возможно я её не замечаю) ибо при выделении сцены (нажатия левой кнопкой мыши) её тоже нигде не вижу.(Также нажатие правой кнопкой мыши по сцене в билде тоже не привёл к желаемым результатам).

Comment: Добавил пояснение в ответ.